# Can't use the coordinate variables when using matplotlib Rectangle selector

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to use this rectangle selector example from Matplotlib to crop image, but everytime I run this code, it will show "NameError: name 'x1' is not defined", but I already define them as global variable and name them in the line_select_callback function. I originally think when I click and release, the coordinate data of where I click and release will be save in x1,x2,y1,y2, then I will be able use them to crop the original image, but it seems something is wrong and I don't know why.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def line_select_callback(eclick, erelease):

    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    'eclick and erelease are the press and release events'
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    print("(%3.2f, %3.2f) --> (%3.2f, %3.2f)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
    print(" The button you used were: %s %s" % (eclick.button, erelease.button))


def toggle_selector(event):
    print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['A', 'a'] and not toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector activated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
filename="C:\\Users\\motorsgroup\\Desktop\\test.png"
im = Image.open(filename)
arr = np.asarray(im)
plt_image=plt.imshow(arr)

print("\n      click  -->  release")

# drawtype is 'box' or 'line' or 'none'
toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                                      button=[1, 3],  # don't use middle button
                                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       interactive=True)
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
plt.show()

newim = arr[int(x1):int(x2),int(y2):int(y1)]
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. When I run the above there is no error, and `print x1, y1, x2, y2` will print the coordinates of the rectangle selector. Of course you will have to first have selected some region, otherwise `x1, y1, x2, y2` are not defined.

Comment: Hi, It seems like spyder(from Anaconda) has some bug with it, if I change to notepad++, there is no error too.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. There are different ways to run code from spyder. I would guess that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529082/spyder-interactive-plot-wait-for-the-plot-to-be-closed-to-continue) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I change the option of my preference in spyder now, it works. But when I want to save the image, the system will shut down...This is my code, which I add after the above code. "plt.imsave("C:\\Users\\motorsgroup\\Desktop\\test.png",newim)"

Comment: What do you mean by "the system will shut down"?